# Screen Capturing IN IOS

Tags: ios

I have searched it on net many times but didn't get a proper solution. I want to implement screen recording video in IOS.  Let me make it more clear. Suppose I am playing a game and after playing that game , I want to replay that game to check how well I have played the game. So ultimately I want to record every action performed on screen. Switching from one screen to another , coming back to root screen etc.  Every action must be recorded.  I am tiered of searching it on google. Can anybody tell me how to implement it ?
Any help will highly be appreciated. 
Thanks in advance.

Comment: The only way I can think of doing this is using something like Reflector. You can't do this on the device due to sand boxing.

Comment: https://github.com/wess/Glimpse ?
You can do it, only in your own app. It seems that the only way is to take photo (screenshot image), and the make a video from them.
There is a few answers in "Related" at the right of the page.

Comment: Agree with Larme. Take screenshots and then make video

Answer (score 0):

this might be helpful checkout

http://codethink.no-ip.org/wordpress/archives/673

Answer (score 0):

Been there - just record the user actions and everything that affects the game. When you want to generate the video, just replay every user action in your world and instead of rendering the UI to the screen, generate video frames.

One of the typical problems is adding audio (music/sound effects) to the video but that would require a separate questions.

If you don't want to generate a video file but only replay the actions on your device, then you can just disable user interaction and replay the user actions directly.